# JQTouch android webView configuration

Tags: android, webview, jqtouch

I'm  developing an application which is mainly a webview and will display a JQTouch UI.  Two of the 3 views work just fine, however, I have a view which loads another page with a form which does not work at all.  This view loads up just fine but when I click the link to go to the form the link just stays highlighted and nothing happens.  I have overriden all of the methods in webviewclient and webchromeclient and placed breakpoints within with no luck.  None of the hooks catch when I click the links.

The part that truly confounds me is that it works in the phones browser but not in my webview.  Is there a setting on webview that I may be missing which would make it act like the phones browser?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The fix for this was to override onLoadResource as the link was being treated as a resource and not a new page load.  I tried calling webView.loadUrl right in the override of loadREsource but that caused an endless loop so  I had to write some logic to load the url properly into my webView.  This seems a bit hacked but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this was to override onLoadResource as the link was being treated as a resource and not a new page load. I tried calling webView.loadUrl right in the override of loadREsource but that caused an endless loop so I had to write some logic to load the url properly into my webView. This seems a bit hacked but it works.